# Android Mixing Java and Kotlin , can't find Kotlin files

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've an existing Java project, I am trying to add a Kotlin activity but it's not listed in java files in android studio.

Inputs:
kotlin files are added to main folder like this:

[image]

Gradle project is updated like this:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
```

Gradle app level is updated like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

finally in android studio, can't find Kotlin activity. only java files are listed.

[image]

did I miss any configuration?

Comment: You can add a kotlin activity in the java package. you don't need to create a separate package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to add another package in this case, just add another activity with Kotlin language like this (source language should be Kotlin):

[image]